# Office-JS error

Tags: typescript, office-js

I am trying to use async/await in office-js add on according to [this guide](https://github.com/Zlatkovsky/BuildingOfficeAddins) and I am having what I assume is typescript compilation issue that I simply can't solve myself...  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Error message:

> JavaScript critical error at line 10, column 52 in https://localhost:44394/Home.js\n\nSCRIPT1005: Expected '('

#### Typescript Code:

```
Word.run(async function (context) {
// ...
await context.sync();
});
```

#### Compiled java script code:

line 10 in error is the `return __awaiter = ....`

```
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
    function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
    function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
    function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(result.value); }).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
    step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
});
};
Word.run(function (context) {
return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    // ...
    yield context.sync();
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the compiled code, it looks like TypeScript is targeting ES **6+**, not ES5.  ES5 is what runs on the standard browser.

Your need to change the compilation options to target ES5 (and adding a libraries definition of "es2015", so you can use Promises from a compiler's perspective, and also including a library/polyfill for Promises at runtime).

PS:  If you can point out what exact portion of the website or book led you off-stray, I am happy to add a clarifying comment there.

Comment: But this was just the cause, I set it as 'ES 6' as my own trouble shooting step which broke something else.  I think the real problem is that I do not know how to set 'es2015' in Visual Studio community 2017 without creating 'tsconfig.jason' file in my directory.  The reason I do not want to create this file is because when I do - it seems to break bunch of things I cant seem to fix (and not for the lack of effort..).

In short, what is unclear to me, is how to set up office project with Typescript in visual studio.  I'm not sure if you think that's in the scope of your book or not..

Comment: I see.  For what it's worth, have you tried Visual Studio Code (and also the configuration file created by "yo office")?  I think I describe it in chapter 3 of my book (note that I'm about to go on vacation for 2 weeks, though, so can't really check or help with this now, unfortunately)

Comment: I have not tried Visual Studio Code, but I will tonight.  You did answer my question, but I cannot mark it as an answer - sorry.  Cheers.

Comment: Your suggestion to try Visual  Studio Code and Yo Office was excellent.  Not only did it solve all my problems, but it also set me up for success with other packages like browser sync.  Thanks :)